# What do you call a scene of a music clip where the singer is seen singing?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a scene of a music clip where the singer is seen singing? I think clip is the generic word for a sequence in a music clip, but I can't think of the word used for the clips where the singer is seen singing. Is there a special word for it? I am pretty sure there isn't. If now, how do people refer to it in a quick way, because "clip where the singer is seen singing" is a big mouthful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is perhaps a term used by producers of music videos.  I've never had to use it.

Checking some online essays about pop videos, they speak of  "Performance"

> switching between narrative and performance shots with close up lip-syncs and shots of the band miming

> Performance videos focus on the artist performing, alone or in front of an audience.

> The video cuts between a narrative of a woman fighting with a lover, and clips of the band performing in a brightly lit room.